# Stopping JQuery promise with failure from propagating into wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

My application has a bunch of `$.ajax` calls that mostly have `.done` and `.fail` functions.

I want to write a wrapper around the Ajax call, so that if a function does not have a `.fail` function, or if the `.fail` function does not handle a given error (for example it only handles 404, but I get back a 403), then I want the wrapper to handle it as a fallback.

Here's what I've written:

```
function DoAjax(fn, errorText) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var result = fn();
    if (result === undefined)
        throw 'Function passed into DoAjax has not returned a promise.';
    result.always(function () {
        deferred.resolve(result);
    });
    result.fail(function () {
        alert('fail');
        deferred.fail();
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

It works mostly as I intend, except that the fail will execute twice - once in the method DoAjax, the other at the site of the Ajax call.

I execute `DoAjax` like this:

```
DoAjax(function () {
        var ajaxCall = $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: baseUrl + "api/test"
        });

        ajaxCall.fail(function() { alert('failed the call'); });

        return ajaxCall;
});
```

I believe I can probably accomplish this by manually creating a $.deferred and then doing the $.ajax call around that, but would rather not have another wrapper around it.

I'm using jQuery 2.2.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Is it 3+ ?

Comment: @charlietfl 2.2 can upgrade if required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's time to do some hard-core learning. Several things need to be taken on board :

1. `.done()` and `.fail()` are just `jQuery.ajax()` options without the socalled "filtering power" of `.then(successCallback, errorCallback)` (or `.then()`/`.catch()` in jQuery 3+). In other words, whatever is returned from `.done()` and `.fail()` callbacks has no downstream effect on a jqxhr promise chain.
2. At jQuery <3, an errorCallback doesn't automatically catch an error. The default behaviour is to remain on the promise chain's error path. In order to give an errorCallback 'catch' behaviour, then you must return a resolved promise from it. At jQuery 3+, an errorCallback catches by default but you can either return a rejected promise or throw to propagate the error condision.
3. Your `fn()`, in this case, returns `jqxhr`, not a result. Therefore, as written, the `if(result === undefined)` test will always return `false`. The result that the jqxhr eventually delivers can't be tested in this way.
4. If you are uncertain whether a function returns a value or a Promise, then wrap the returned value/object in `jQuery.when(...)`, eg `$.when(fn())`.
5. With (3) taken care of, you can chain directly from the promise returned by `jQuery.when(...)`. There's no need for an explicit `$.Deferred()`.

Try this :

```
var baseUrl = '/';
function DoAjax(fn) {
    return $.when(fn()) // no need to test for fn() not returning a promise. `$.when(fn())` forces any non-Promise to Promise.
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log('success!', response);
    }).then(null, function(err) {
        console.error('B', err); // (LOG_2)
    });
}

DoAjax(function () {
    return $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: baseUrl + "api/test"
    }).then(null, function(jqxhr, textStatus) {
        var err = new Error('Whoops! ' + jqxhr.status + ': ' + textStatus);
        console.error('A', err);

        // "throw behaviour"
        return err; // propagate the error (jQuery <3) or `throw err;` (jQuery 3+)

        // "catch behaviour"
        // return $.when('default response'); // "2" mutate failure into success (jQuery <3) or `return 'default response';` (jQuery 3+)
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jawtzbqf/2/)**

Now try swapping out the lines labelled "propagate behaviour" and "catch behaviour" and observe the difference in the log.

Don't worry if you don't get it immediately. Learning this stuff takes time.

If you have a choice, then work jQuery 3+, in which jqxhr and other Promises are far closer to javascript's native `Promise` than in jQuery <3.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this up. I didn't use your exact solution (I ended up abstracting it), but it gave me what I needed to do. Thanks again, have a nice day.

Comment: Pleased to be of assistance. Good luck with it.